# autosuggest using jquery need suggestion

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

i need to use auto suggest in my website and i need to suggest multiple lines say
if someone search for ex

```
ex 
  example
   one
  example2
   two
  example 3
```

is it is possible to do it using jquery...

Answer (score 0):

check : JQueryUI Autocomplete plugin

http://jqueryui.com/demos/

Comment: ya i checked it but i need something similar to this http://i.imgur.com/mCLnd.png